# Change color from black to white

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I need to make this leaf white and not black, no background color on Photoshop. Any help?
[image]

Comment: Following the instructions from the top answer to this question should get you what you want: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4154/photoshop-cs5-how-to-create-a-layer-mask-from-a-layer Just create a new white layer and add the layer mask to that.

Comment: It's not a black and white image.. it's a CMYK file that is a dark grey and white. Do you want it to be slightly off-white? You'll need to adjust it so the black is actually black.

Answer (score 3):

1. Click on the “magic wand tool”
2. Click on any white part of the image (like the top right corner) to select the white parts
3. Right click then choose “select inverse”
4. Click on “create new fill or adjustment layer” (the circle icon that looks like the yin yang symbol without the swirls or dots in the bottom right corner)
5. Click on solid color
6. Then click on white or type in the color code ffffff next to the #
7. Click Ok
8. Click on the layer underneath the one that was just created and tap on the delete button

Hope this helps!

Comment: Using magic wand could leave unwanted "shadows" along the contur of the shape. See my answer for an alternative way.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers will work, but there is a lot of manual work involved and using magic wand in this case is not the best way. It will distort the contour and there is a risk of unwanted "shadows" from the original image.

Instead you should try the following:

- Press `Ctrl+A` to select all of the image.
- Press `Ctrl+C` to copy the image to clipboard.
- Create a new "Solid Color" fill layer.

[image: Add solid color layer]

- Select the color white (or any other color - that's the cool part!).
- Hold down `Alt` and left click on the mask of the "Solid color" layer to switch to "mask view".

[image: Mask view]

- Press `Ctrl+V` to paste in the image.
- Press `Ctrl+D` to deselect everything. (It is good practice to deselect at this stage so you can invert the entire mask and not just the selection. This will make it possible to move around the image later without getting unwanted edges.)
- Press `Ctrl+I` to invert the mask.
- Now, if you zoom in on the mask you can see that it is not 100% clean. While the mask is still highlighted, select `Image-Adjustments-Brightness/Contrast` and adjust until the black and white areas look clean. (You could also use curves, levels or other tools to achieve this). Be careful not to ruin the anti-aliased edge of your graphics!

[image: Before]

[image: Brightness/Contrast]

[image: After]

- After adjusting the mask, left click on the color of the "Solid Color" layer to return to "normal mode".

Now you have a dynamic, transparent solid color layer. You can change the color if you want and you can keep editing the mask. If you need a background color, make it a solid color layer too! That way you can change both colors with ease.

[image: Multi-colored]

Answer (score 0):

Your photo is very noisy. The noise is mostly JPG artifacts. They are especially bad if the photo has sharp edges, as yours. You have probably tried to invert your photo and delete the black background by selecting it by the Magic Wand and pressing DEL. The result:

[image]

Let's do it a little better from the start:

- open your image
- in the Layers panel doubleclick the background layer to make it a layer
- add a new layer below your photo. Rename it to "test background" and fill it with a solid but not especially bright color.
- goto your photo layer. Invert it (Image > Adjustments > Invert)
- There are plenty of nearly black and nearly white JPG artifacts. Take the levels tool to force them to black and white. Move the input limiters as follows:

[image]

- select the black background by the magic wand. Have a low tolerance, say =5 and keep Anti-alias = selected.
- press DEL. The result is now better, but there's much grey dirt at the edges of the white parts:

[image]

- Clean the white parts. Select the empty background by the magic wand. Goto Select > Inverse to get the white parts selected
- Fill the selected area with white by painting over it by a big (500 pix) solid (hardness = 100%) brush.Do not use the paint bucket, because it has its own quite complex settings. Paint over every place several times to be sure all is fixed.
- the anti-aliasing leak the paint over the border exessively, if some place is painted several times. The exessive white on the background must be deleted:
- goto Select > Inverse, press DEL. Ready.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's Simple!
Follow these steps.

1) Select the white part with "Magic Wand Tool" and "delete" white part
2) Click on "Add a layer style" i.e "fx" button from the layers panel.
3) Select "Color Overlay"
4) Make color to "white" blend mode is normal and opacity 100%
5) click "ok"

That's it.